# Django - How to add a validator to form field (instead of setting it)

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x

In Django, you can specify the validators to a given form field by:

```
def SomeForm(forms.Form):
    field_1 = forms.CharField()
    field_2 = forms.CharField(validators=[...])
```

However, what if I only want to add a single validator onto the field? I am searching for a solution that only adds and does not replace any validators that may be inherent or inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from sources ([https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py)) there are no default_validators set for CharField, only MaxLengthValidator added while creation, so you can feel free to set your own validators.

By the way, if you check this line ([https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py#L535](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L535)) you will see that default validators are appended with given on creation validators.